# How should I setup my Azure Network for this particular web scenario

Tags: sql-server, iis, azure, architecture, installation

We're looking at moving off our Hosted company and onto Azure.

**We're not sure what type of network setup we need to do with Azure. Eg. availability sets, etc**

We currently have

- 1x VM IIS Website (main site)
- 1x VM IIS Website (totally separate site with different UI/content etc).
- 1x VM IIS Webiste (json api).
- 1x dedicated Sql Server 2012 box all tricked out big time with RAID 10, SSD, 24Gig Ram.

(no IIS VM's are load balanced or scaled).

We're not doing -anything- special with IIS (eg. custom sections unlocked, etc) so we're hoping to move these over to WAWS so we can scale when needs be. (eg. add more instances).

SQL Server 2012 uses FTS (oh! le sigh!) so we'll probably go and get an A6 2012 R1 VM with SQL Standard (we need to be able to profile if a failure happens in production).

So, what we're hoping to setup is something like the following

- SQL Server in Azure. IP Whitelist it for a) the Azure website private VLAN thingy (is this possible? and b) about 3 public IP's.
- 3x WAWS for our IIS sites.

But we want to be able to update. Say, the main website and not incur any downtime for the users. (NOTE: Lets assume we're not doing any DB maintenance).

So, is there something special we can do here to have .. say .. 1 instance up, the 2nd get's auto updated, then it does the other one? Do we need to worry about load balancing?

eg. Put webs on one subnet . 192.168.1.x, DB on a 2nd subnet 192.168.2.x ... and then do this and that, etc.

Incidentally, I'm not sure if that's possible.

Lastly, I'm hoping to avoid using VMs for the websites or web workers for the websites, because I've found using WAWS so nice and less support/maintenance required.

Answer (score 1):

You loaded that up with a lot of questions. I'll avoid the opinion-based ones (such as what you *should* do to set this up), and tackle the objective ones:

Azure Web Sites: Very easy to push code to, and simple to update without downtime, assuming you have more than one instance running (the changes are propagated, and not all at the exact same time to all instances). However: Azure Web Sites does not offer dedicated outbound IP addresses (only dedicated incoming, if you purchase an ssl cert). Therefore, you cannot include a site hosted in WAWS within a virtual network, nor can you add it to an IP whitelist on a VM's endpoint ACL.

Web Sites will take care of load-balancing for you, assuming you scale to multiple instances. By the way: those same instances would host all of your websites. Just like, with Cloud Services, you can deploy multiple websites to the same Web Role.

If you want to IP-whitelist your website, you'd need to go with cloud services (web role), or VM. Web Roles are fairly straightforward to construct; underneath, they're just Windows Server VMs. You have no OS maintenance to worry about; you just maintain the code project in Visual Studio, and push up a deployment package when it's time to update the app.

Also keep this in mind: with either Web Sites or Cloud Services (or VMs, for that matter), if you have static content such as CSS, images, Javascript, etc., you can store that in blob storage and update this content independent of your deployed code (assuming you've adjusted your app to point to blob storage for the source of such content).

Regarding availability sets: This is a mechanism for combining multiple virtual machines into a high-availability configuration: the VMs are spread out across racks, removing single-point-of-failure (e.g. top-of-rack router fails; you don't want all your VMs knocked out because of that). VMs in an availability set are also updated separately when it comes time for Host OS update (the OS running beneath the VMs). Otherwise, they'd all have the potential to be updated simultaneously.

Comment: Ok - so you've mentioned some important things about the options I can use (which is very very helpful!). Awesome. I didn't know about the WAWS incoming IP, for example. But I would love some OPINION-BASED suggestions also please. If baked up by a 'why' .. then it will be a valuable answer, IMO. Please? I'm open to all ideas.  -or- I'm happy to chat on Jabbr.net if opinions are allowed here on SO. :) (I know the rest of the JabbR peeps would be -very- interested :)